# R: For-Loop in RCURL

Tags: r, for-loop, rcurl

I am really new to R. That is probably why my question is really newbie.

My goal is to retrieve data through an API call. However, due the quota i have to run the same URL Call several times by changing the parameter pages e.g. from 0:24 page.

I am using RCurl for the procedure. I could not find out where the for-loop has to be started to list data from the calls 0: 24:

```
   URL <- paste(base.html.string,
               '/', ID,
               '/data/', Action,
               '?queryId=', Query,
               '&startDate=', startDate,
               '&search=', SearchQuery,
               '&endDate=', endDate,
               '&pageSize=', results,
               '&page=',pages,
               '&access_token=', Access_token,
               '&orderBy=date',
               sep = '')


Content <- getURLContent(URL)
```

---

Comment: is `pages` your range 0:24?

Comment: Give the httr package a look. The `GET()` function provides a friendlier interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [page 9 of RCurl reference](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/RCurl.pdf) for more details. I believe this should work. I haven't tested it myself though.

```
g <- multiTextGatherer(URLs)
cl = getCurlHandle(verbose=T)
txt = getURL(URLs, write = g, curl = cl)
```

Answer (score 0):

lapply(0:24,function (i)paste(base.html.string, '/', ID, '/data/', Action, '?queryId=', Query, '&startDate=', startDate, '&search=', SearchQuery, '&endDate=', endDate, '&pageSize=', results, '&page=',i, '&access_token=', Access_token, '&orderBy=date', sep = '')%>% getUrlContent)

But this is not the best way to do what you want. And for a "newbie" api calls in a loop are fairly complex I would think. You can pass your parsers into the RHS chain as well